# CairoSVG wants "SVG files that are XML tree" and won't read my SVG file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, svg, cairo

I'm trying to convert an SVG file which I wrote for use in Adobe Illustrator. It displays fine in browsers, but image editors do not like it, so I want to try to use CairoSVG to convert it to PS, but I get the error:

```
 AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'xml_tree'
```

I tried it with the original file which was like this:

```
<svg height="240" width="310" viewBox="0 0 310 240"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
   <defs>
      ...
   </defs>
   ...
</svg>
```

I also tried it with a document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg height="240" width="310" viewBox="0 0 310 240"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
   <defs>
      ...
   </defs>
   ...
</svg>
```

How do I need to change my SVG file to be properly readable?